# HQL left join not working

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

Trying to write the equivalent hql query for the following sql query:

(SQL):

```
SELECT * FROM Game g LEFT JOIN RollbackGame rb ON g.id = rb.id WHERE rb.gameId IS NULL
```

(HQL):

```
SELECT g FROM Game g LEFT JOIN RollbackGame rb WITH g.id = rb.gameId WHERE rb.gameId IS NULL
```

The HQL is not working for me, any ideas why? (is it even possible to achieve with hql?)

EDIT: I get this kind of error:

```
Path expected for join! [SELECT g FROM com.xxx.model.game.Game g LEFT JOIN RollbackGame AS rb WITH g.id = rb.gameId WHERE rb.gameId IS NULL
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your **HQL** should be like below:

```
SELECT g FROM Game g LEFT JOIN RollbackGame AS rb WITH g.id = rb.gameId WHERE rb.gameId IS NULL
```

you forgot **AS** keyword before alias.

Comment: I get the following error:  Path expected for join! [SELECT g FROM com.xxx.model.game.Game g LEFT JOIN RollbackGame AS rb WITH g.id = rb.gameId WHERE rb.gameId IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

You have an association of `Game` and `RollbackGame`:

```
class RollbackGame{

   @ManyToOne
   Game game;
}

class Game{

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="game")
   Set<RollbackGame> rollbackGames;
}
```

You don't need to explicitly declare `WITH`. So the HQL will be:

```
SELECT g FROM Game g LEFT JOIN g.rollbackGames rb WHERE rb.game IS NULL
```